# How to monitor garbage collection to see what is GC'd?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, visualvm

I have a huge Java app (Running Jdk7 64Bit, Weblogic 12). Running the application without anyone calling it - aka just idling. I can see every 3-4 minutes there is a 300Mb spike and then it is garbage collected using visual vm.

[image]

I took several stack traces and nothing is busy at the time when it was taken. We also make use of EHCache and added logging to log the results. Once the app is up and running I cannot see anything in the logs (while it is idling) but still there is this 300mb garbage collection that takes place.

Taking a heap dump when the used space is low and 300mb afterwards do not show much of a difference using eclipse memory analyser with the memory allocations looking the same:

[image]

Is there a way to see what is being garbage collected? And I do understand that there will be constant collection but is 300mb ok?

Comment: Have you checked if there is an abnormal creation of objects?

Comment: Trying to find out what has been collected will not lead to anywhere, as despite the colloquial name, nothing will be collected. The JVM detects what is still reachable, i.e. *not* garbage, that’s why you see so little difference in the heap dumps. With a few exceptions, you can only dump what is reachable. To find out, what is happening, you have to trace the *allocations*, which your monitoring tools should support as well. But don’t be surprised, if it turns out that the monitoring tools themselves are causing it…

Comment: That graph looks pretty normal to me. Your application - or rather Weblogic - is gradually adding more stuff to the heap at a constant rate over time and then at around the 750Mb threshold, the garbage collector runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is the impact of *monitoring* to your application, given that it's implemented in Java. I would suggest that you add `-XX:+PrintGCDetails`  to your commandline, and check how often GCs happen with and without monitoring.

And yes, that rate of garbage (300MB/5min) is normal for JMX. Also, how huge is your application? More than 32 GB RAM?

Comment: Thanks. :)

I did the following:

1. I logged onto the weblogic console and undeploy all artifacts. Still the same behavior.

2. I then added the PrintGCDetails as you suggested. And it only GC'd the 300 odd mb if I have visualVM connected.

Comment: That's because VisualVM is polling for changes; if you have some other kind of monitoring tool that hooks into JMX, then you'll see it again (JMX can't easily push changes to monitors). But as I said, that's OK.

Answer (score 2):

Your memory behavior is not problematic. Even if your application is idle, many things are going on, causing the memory allocation you are observing. I presume you are monitoring total heap including young generation. Thus every object allocated will show up on your graphs. A young GC every 3-4 minutes absolutely normal and takes only a few ms each time.

So I would switch to monitoring old generation only, and you'll have a very flat line and no GCs at all.